# GNU Make: Archiving library members with replacement

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What is the difference between the two options below? Wouldn't `$<` expand to only one `requisite` (by definition "the first one") in both cases?

**Option 1:**

```
libcounter.a(lexer.o): lexer.o
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<

libcounter.a(counter.o): counter.o
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<
```

**Option 2:**

```
libcounter.a: lexer.o
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<

libcounter.a: counter.o
  $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $<
```

ARFLAGS holds `rv` in both cases.

As a reference, the examples are taken from the book [Managing Projects with GNU Make](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first option, `make` knows enough to look inside `libcounter.a` at the `lexer.o` object to see if it needs to update the library with the new object. In the second option, the timestamp on the library itself is compared with the object, which may lead to missed updates of the library - e.g. imagine 1) `lexer.o` gets built, then 2) `counter.o` gets built, then 3) `libcounter.a` gets new `lexer.o` added; now at this point, the timestamp on `libcounter.a` is newer than `counter.o`, so `make` wrongly concludes it does not need to add the new `counter.o` to the library.